# Instance <Seller at 0x7f789524c910> cannot be refreshed - it's not persistent and does not contain a full primary key

Tags: python, fastapi

Having this error :

```
Instance <Seller at 0x7f789524c910> cannot be refreshed - it's not 
persistent and does not contain a full primary key.
```

When i try to send a POST REQUEST with Fastapi

```py
class Seller(Base):
    __table__ = Table('seller', metadata,
                autoload=True,
                autoload_with=engine,
                schema='seller')
        
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'primary_key': __table__.c.id_seller
    }
    
    
@app.post("/create_seller/")
def create_seller(seller:schemas.Seller:
    db = Session()
    db_seller= Seller(**seller.dict())
    print(db_seller)
    try:
        db.add(db_seller)
    except Exception as e :
        print(str(e))
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_seller)
    return db_seller
```

My pydantic Scehma is :

```py
class Seller(BaseModel):
    
    id_brand : int
    updated_by_user : str
    
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

I don't set the `seller_id` on my schema because have a `identity(1,1)` set on the created database. So when I made the request with the `seller_id`, it gives another error.

DB SCHEMA TABLE :

```
CREATE TABLE [test].[seller]( 
[id_seller] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
[id_brand] [int] NULL, [last_update] [datetime] NULL, 
[updated_by_user] [varchar](200) NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [UQ_id_seller_id_brand] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ( 
[id_seller] ASC, 
[id_brand] ASC )
WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

Comment: Can you please share with us actual SQL schema for the database table in question.

Comment: of course , i`m add this to the question.